# Dialog Window Title

Tags: office-js

I'm using Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync to display a popup dialog.

In Excel for Windows, the Window title is shown as the addin name.

In Excel Online, the window title is 'Message from Add-in: ' followed by the addin name. This doesn't look too good.

Is it possible to

(a) provide the title as parameter to the api

(b) use the html page title

or at least (c) remove the text 'Message from Add-in: ' in the case of Excel Online

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a way to change the dialog title, but it's a great idea. Please suggest this on [Office Developer Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/). (Someone may have already made the suggestion, so please search for it first and vote it up if it is already there.)

Comment: Thanks. I have updated this.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17196659-improve-custom-dialog